# Invalid template when adding modules to azuredeploy.parameters.json file

Tags: paas, deployment, arm-template, infrastructure, azure-resource-manager

I am using the provided `ARM Templates` to deploy a `Sitecore 9.3 XP Scaled` topology to `Azure PaaS`, and then planning to add some adjustments. It all went mostly fine, but I'm stuck now when I tried to add `SXA+PS` as a module.
Following the documentation, I added this snippet to the `azuredeploy.parameters.json` file:

```
"modules": {
  "value": {
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "sxa",
        "templateLink": "",
        "parameters": {
          "cdSxaMsDeployPackageUrl": "",
          "cmSxaMsDeployPackageUrl": "",
          "speMsDeployPackageUrl": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "bootloader",
        "templateLink": "",
        "parameters": {
          "msDeployPackageUrl": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and populated with the right values. I do have the right templates and scwdp packages uploaded to my blob storage, just the same as the other templates and packages that are actually working.

However, once I add the `"modules"`, I am getting this error from the `azuredeploy.json` template, which is not a valid template anymore:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 12:13:25 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'dependencies' is not valid: The language expression property 'items' doesn't exist, available properties are 'CliXml'.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.
```

Which is referring to this variable in the main template:

```
"dependencies": "[concat(variables('defaultDependency'), parameters('modules').items)]"
```

which I haven't changed, and seems to be just like that from the previous versions.
Nothing came up from googling this. Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Any news on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the parameter section of your `azuredeploy.json` ARM template instead of your `azuredeploy.parameters.json` parameter file.

So the azuredeploy.json will look something like this (this snippet assumes you have uploaded your Sitecore WDPs to a blob storage and is only an example for the JSS module. The bootloader is always required)

```
"parameters": {
"modules": {
  "type": "secureObject",
  "defaultValue": {
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "empty",
        "templateLink": "[concat(uri(parameters('templateLinkBase'), 'nested/emptyAddon.json'), parameters('templateLinkAccessToken'))]",
        "parameters": {
        }
      },
       {
      "name": "bootloader",
      "templateLink": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/master/Sitecore%2010.2.0/XM/addons/bootloader.json",
      "parameters": {
        "msDeployPackageUrl" : "https://xxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/sitecorepwd/Sitecore.Cloud.Integration.Bootload.wdp.zip"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "jss",
      "templateLink": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/master/JSS%2019.0.0/xm/azuredeploy.json",
      "parameters":
      {
        "jssMsDeployPackageUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/sitecorepwd/Sitecore Headless Services Server XM 21.0.583.scwdp.zip",
        "jssCDMsDeployPackageUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/sitecorepwd/Sitecore Headless Services Server XM CD 21.0.583.scwdp.zip"
      }
    }
```

Hope it works for you as well!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).